# Access form(react-final-form) state in the parent component

Tags: reactjs, validation, react-final-form

How do I access form state in the parent component

This is what I am doing (just a brief code, ignore the syntax please)

```
class Parent {
   <listComponent
     onSelect: handler
   >
  handler() {
    // Do this only if the already opened ChildComp in not dirty
     <ChildComp>
  }
}
// Uses react-final-form
class ChildComp {
   <form
      onSubmit: handleSubmit
      render: renderForm
    >
     renderForm ({dirty}){
      // Assigning to a class variable and prompting for unsaved changes which I am able to do
       this.isFormDirty = dirty
      return(
         <InputField>
     );
   }
   </form>
}
```

The problem now is, I am not able to notify the parent not to render the child if the child is dirty in onSelect handler().
I cannot do setState in the render method, at least I could have notified using componentDidUpdate
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copied from [Issue #551](https://github.com/final-form/react-final-form/issues/551#issuecomment-510880871):

---

Another possibility is that there's a recent API change that [lets you provide your own form instance](https://github.com/final-form/react-final-form#form-formapi) to `<Form>`, so something like this could work:

```
import { createForm } from 'final-form'

function TestForm() {
  const formRef = React.useRef(createForm({
    onSubmit: myOnSubmit
  })
  return (
    <div>
      <Form form={formRef.current}>
        {({ handleSubmit, form }) => (
          <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}> ... fields ... </form>
        )}
      </Form>
      <button onClick={() => formRef.current.reset()}>Reset</button>
    </div>
  )
}
```